# Разделить сообщение на мелкие с сохранением разделителя

Tags: c++

Есть код к примеру:

```
char str[] = "%fds%f%dssa%sss";
char* tokenStr = strtok(buffer, "%");
while (tokenStr != NULL)
{
    tokenStr = ...//сохранение в другую переменную или какие-то действия
    tokenStr = strtok(NULL, "%");
}
```

вывод:

```
fds
f
dssa
sss
```

но необходимо сохранить % в сообщении. Ожидаемый вывод:

```
%fds
%f
%dssa
%sss
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что я не могу использовать пространство имен std и стандартные библиотеки типа string и вектор. Ограничения связаны с тем, что пишу программу для контроллера Pixhawk, и там нет реализации стандартных бибилиотек. https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/style-guide.html#no-standard-library.
Одна из идей при сохранении `tokenStr`в другую переменную на позицию `[0]` помещать желаемый `%`, но мне кажется не очень здравой идеей.

Comment: Что мешает вам при выводе сначала отправить %, а потом само сообщение? Не знаю как организован вывод в вашем приложении, но что-то типа ```cout << "%" << tokenStr << endl;```

Comment: @SelfishCrawler это фактически получается искусственное добавление % к полученному сообщению

Comment: Не понимаю, чем Вас это не устраивает. Вы отсылаете 1 байт и 4 байта, либо отсылаете 5 байт. В конечном итоге вы получите 5 байт.